# Chat server and client implementation?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, winsock, lan

I've been *dying* to implement a chat server in C and Winsock for a long time now, but I haven't taken the time. Partly, because I'm still unsure of some of the conceptual ideas about building a server on Windows OS'es for something like chat.

Here are some of the issues I've been thinking about :

- How will user x connect to my server over a generic LAN
  without me relying on them to type in a network address( e.g. address
  could be invalid, redirected to a different server, etc. )
- If I use broadcasting to solve the above problem, will that be reliable enough for chat?
- Will that potentially DDos a LAN since the packets will be be forcibly handled on every machine and may take a lot of bandwidth if enough people join?
- What is the difference between multicasting and broadcasting? Is multicasting *truly* superior?
- Etc.

Per request, my definition of reliability would be that I can get *most* of the data consistently in sent packets. In other words, I don't mind a few dropped packets, but I do mind if the data gets messed up quite a lot along the way.

Currently, I have a lot more questions than answers, but the main point I'm getting at is this :

### What is the safest and most reliable way of implementing a chat over a LAN in C and Winsock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> How will user x connect to my server over a generic LAN without me relying 
> on them to type in a network address( e.g. address could be
> invalid, redirected to a different server, etc. )
> ```

Use a closed list of known servers, or use some broadcast based autodiscovery system.

> ```
> If I use broadcasting to solve the above problem, will that be reliable 
> enough for chat?
> ```

Define your requirements for reliability.

> Will that potentially DDos a LAN since the packets will be be forcibly
>      handled on every machine and may take a lot of bandwidth if enough
>      people join?

It's a chat... the amount of generated packets will be comparatively short and small.

> What is the difference between multicasting and broadcasting? Is 
>      multicasting truly superior?

Search the web. There are lots of resources and information about multicasting, most precisely, IP multicasting. In short:

- Broadcast delivers to all hosts on a broadcast domain. Multicast delivers to all hosts that have explicity joined a multicast group, which may not be in the same broadcast domain (see last point).
- Broadcast forces a switch to forward broadcast packets to all its interfaces. Intelligent switches can benefit from peeking at IGMP packets to know which interfaces multicast packets have to be forwarded to.
- Broadcast cannot treepass a broadcast domain. Multicast packets can traverse a router, if it's configured to route multicast (search for `M-bone`)